# How to reference go-flag IsSet, functional code example needed

Tags: go, go-flag

New to Go, and having a basic conceptual problem (I think)...

Trying to use github.com/jessevdk/go-flags and have it mostly working.  --help and whatnot are working fine, flags are being passed, etc.

I need to understand if a option was set via a flag or via go-flags parser using the provided default value.  It appears go-flags has an "IsSet" function, but I'm clueless how to reference it.  Presume:

```
var opts struct {
    Port int `short:"p" long:"Port" description:"IP port" default:"1111"
}
_, err := flags.Parse(&opts)
```

I can reference the value via "opts.Port", but how can I find out if the option was set via a flag or default?   Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Figured this out:

`parser := flags.NewParser(&opts, flags.Default)
o := parser.FindOptionByLongName("Port)
if o.IsSet() {}`

Problme is that `IsSet()` is true if the flag was used on the command line OR if it was set via the default.

So solved the surface problem of referencing `IsSet()` but still hunting for an ability to tell which occured, since I want the flag defaults to show in --help.

Answer (score 0):

Go newbie here as well. `IsSetDefault()` is also available. (Perhaps, it was added since you asked and answered your question.)